# Using Facebook API disables my account

Tags: php, facebook, web-services, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Facebook API in my web app. I've created a dedicated FB account to create the FB app and access it through the API.

I'm not aware or any wrongdoing, I'm not scraping the site, I'm using the API, I'm not sending too many requests too fast, yet each time I try to do this my account is disabled. I'm asked to submit a photo of me to prove my identity but they never unblock the account and it's essentially dead.

I've created many accounts on multiple IPs and each time they disable it after a first few requests, so it's not a question of my IP being flagged. I've tried verifying the accounts before using them with a phone number, but it makes no difference. I've tried faking a real activity, liking pages, adding friends etc., but it makes no difference either. I've tried making it a Business Manager Account, again no difference. I don't want to use my real personal account, because I don't want it to be endangered by a possible deletion.

What am I doing wrong? How to properly use the Facebook API? I'm using their official PHP library. I don't have this problem with other social networks.

Example code:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => $app_id,
        'app_secret' => $app_secret,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $access_token);
```

Even after executing only this my accounts gets disabled.

Comment: This issue is that you are creating "fake" accounts to create apps on. You are supposed to use your personal Facebook account. Creating multiple facebook accounts is against their terms or service - so when they detected multiple accounts from you, they blocked those accounts and by extension, any application that was associated with it. This has happened to me in the past.

Comment: Indeed, that seems to be the only option. Thanks.

Comment: I am facing this issue too. So what should we do in this case.

Comment: It's exactly as Lix wrote. You need to use a real account. What Facebook considers a real account is hard to tell, but I'm now using an account that is several years old and that I've interacted with over the years as a real person would (likes, posts, messages, ...). Initially I was worried it'll get disabled as well, but it's been 2 months and still nothing, so it seems that's the way.

Comment: Thanks, @mhrvth. I will do this.